# What hands are worth raising with in late position to capture the antes in five card draw poker?

Tags: betting-strategy, 5-card-draw

The game is eight-handed, the antes are 1/8th of a bet, meaning there is one bet in the pot to start.

You probably wouldn't want to bet two small pair in early position, because of the possibility of getting multiple callers. (And the other principle I've learned is that two small pair should either raise or fold but not play for a single bet before the draw.) But if you are in late position and six or seven people have passed, does it make sense to raise with two (small) pair to try to capture the antes? You're probably best before the draw and no one has shown any confidence.

How about raising with a pair of jacks (the minimum) on the "button," or a pair of queens one off the button?